# Find those teams having same state and color

Tags: sql

```
Table: Colors(Colour_id, color, team_id)

Table: Teams(team_id, team_name, state)
```

I want my result set as those teams having the same **state** and **color**

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  And an appropriate database tag.  Do you want teams where *all* colors and states are the same?  Or that just overlap on one of them?

Comment: For example if I am having teams (A,B,C) with state(1,2,1) and their colors are 
like (team A  'red' , team B  'green' , team C 'red') ............... so my result set would be Team A and Team C as they are having same state and color

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables, group by state and color and use `group_concat()` (for Mysql) to get the team names:

```
select t.state, c.color, group_concat(t.team_name) teams
from teams t inner join colors c
on c.team_id = t.team_id
group by t.state, c.color
having count(*) > 1
```

You may use similar functions like `group_concat()` in other databases.

Comment: group_concat is not recognized as built in function in SSMS

Comment: Set the tag of the database that you use.